# How to add caption to a top-and-bottom wrapped image?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I have a two column document where I want to insert an image spanning across the two columns.

I figured that one way to do this is to wrap the text "Top and Bottom" around the image.

However, as soon as I do this, the option to add a Caption to the image simply disappears.

Why does this happen and how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you do not use wrapping text, you keep the image in line with text and use the technique described in the thread that @harrymc has shared with you in his comment.

When done that way, you do not lose the ability to add a caption.